# TestWindow is not a constructor in Stenciljs Unit test

Tags: stenciljs

Getting errors when I run unit test for the component
1) TestWindow is not a constructor
2) Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
Not able to understand how to proceed further. When I try to console element and testWindow, both are coming as undefined.

```
    **tsx file**
    import { Component } from '@stencil/core';
    @Component({
        tag: 'my-header',
        styleUrl: 'my-header.css'
    })
    export class MyHeader {
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>Hello MyHeader!</p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    **Spec file**
    import { TestWindow } from '@stencil/core/testing';
    import { MyHeader } from './my-header';

    describe('my-header', () => {
      it('should build', () => {
        expect(new MyHeader()).toBeTruthy();
      });

      describe('rendering', () => {
        let element: HTMLMyHeaderElement;
        let testWindow: TestWindow;
        beforeEach(async () => {
          testWindow = new TestWindow();
          element = await testWindow.load({
            components: [MyHeader],
            html: '<my-header></my-header>'
          });

        });
        console.log("element ",element);
        console.log("testWindow ",testWindow);
        it('should show content', () => {
          expect(element.textContent).toEqual('');
        });

      });
    });
```

**package.json**
        "devDependencies": {
            "@stencil/core": "~0.16.4",
            "@stencil/sass": "^0.1.1",
            "@types/jest": "23.3.11",
            "@types/puppeteer": "1.6.4",
            "jest": "^23.6.0",
            "jest-cli": "23.6.0",
            "puppeteer": "1.8.0",
            "workbox-build": "3.4.1"
          }
        how can I get rid of those errors or I'm missing something to include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire Stencil unit testing changed in latest versions.
TestWindow is now deprecated in favor of the combination of Jest and Puppeteer.
You should consult the documentation for further explanations about how to test your code: [end to end testing in Stencil](https://stenciljs.com/docs/end-to-end-testing)

Comment: Thanks Gil Fink, I have moved to "newE2EPage"